# python: is it possible to map the values by using string dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to map the data between two data frames (the data are from csv file using pandas) but I got the indexes problem

the first df is df1

```
0         CAT11/06
1         CAT11/100
2         CAT23/223
3         CAT33/14
4         CAT13/14 
5         DOG12/04 
6         DOG24/14
7         CAT24/112
```

the second df is df2

```
0    CAT1
3    CAT2
4    CAT3
5    DOG1
6    DOG2
```

and I would like to make a new data frame to collect the expected data like this and define it as a df3

```
0  CAT1 CAT11/06 | CAT11/100 | CAT13/14
1  CAT2 CAT23/223 | CAT24/112
2  CAT3 CAT33/14
3  DOG1 DOG12/04
4  DOG2 DOG24/14
```

Answer (score 1):

Using two for loop with `in` and `join`

```
df2['col2']=['|'.join(df1[[x in y for y in df1]].tolist()) for x in df2.col1]
df2
Out[347]: 
   col1                         col2
0  CAT1  CAT11/06|CAT11/100|CAT13/14
3  CAT2          CAT23/223|CAT24/112
4  CAT3                     CAT33/14
5  DOG1                     DOG12/04
6  DOG2                     DOG24/14
```

Comment: thank you for your help but i found the error -> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'  :'(

Comment: @Sungjin your df1 is list ?